# Getting Derived attribute from sql database through server

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

This is in my function

```
$http.get('pokemon/distinct-pokemon/' + u.username).then(function(response) {
    $scope.count = response.data
})
```

I want to show here the count of the the distint pokemons

```
<tr class="table-row-data">
   <td class="table-title">Number of unique pokemon</td>
   <td>{{count}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is my server. I'm getting the number of distinct pokemons here by using the query below.

```
app.get('/pokemon/distinct-pokemon/', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('select * from catches', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
          res.send(rows)
        }
    })
})

app.get('/pokemon/distinct-pokemon/:name', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('select count(distinct(pokemon_name)) from catches where username = ?', req.params.name , function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send()
        }
    })
})
```

It works fine but the result is

[image: The result should be only integer 6 not the whole json]

I want the result to be only the number 6 not the whole json

Comment: The query is correct. It works fine but how would i get the integer 6 from the json in the image?

Comment: Well you are not saying where and how you are pushing the result to the td element. 
There is something that needs to be changed there, but I think you can also change `app.get('/pokemon/distinct-pokemon/:name', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('select count(distinct(pokemon_name)) from catches where username = ?', req.params.name , function(err, results) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(results);
        }
    })
})`

Comment: and can you give us more information on how you treat the result of this request and push it to the td?